# Error onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad Admob Interstitial recompensado Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Estoy implementando Admob Interstitial, recompensado en Android Studio, pero tengo este error cuando quiero cargar el anuncio:

> onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad.

Os dejo unir las capturas de código y la configuración de admob.

```
package com.android.proyect;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdListener;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.reward.RewardedVideoAd;

import static android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResource;
import static android.view.Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON;

public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity{


    private RewardedVideoAd mRewardedVideoAd;
    private static final String AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-000000000000000/00000000"; //My code

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the view from singleitemview.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);

        probarboton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);

        //Anuncio probar video
        mRewardedVideoAd = MobileAds.getRewardedVideoAdInstance(this);
        mRewardedVideoAd.setRewardedVideoAdListener(new RewardedVideoAdListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLoaded()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLoaded", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdOpened()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdOpened", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoStarted()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoStarted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdClosed()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdClosed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // Preload the next video ad.
                loadRewardedVideoAd();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewarded(RewardItem rewardItem)
            {
                textView4.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(),"you got %d %s!", rewardItem.getAmount(), rewardItem.getType()));
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication()
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdLeftApplication", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int i)
            {
                Toast.makeText(Welcome.this, "onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        probarboton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Log.i("probar","video");
                System.out.println("click boton probar video");
                if (mRewardedVideoAd.isLoaded()) {
                    mRewardedVideoAd.show();
                }
            }
        });

        requestNewInterstitial();
        loadRewardedVideoAd();
    }

    private void loadRewardedVideoAd() {
        AdRequest adRewardRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        mRewardedVideoAd.loadAd(AD_UNIT_ID, adRewardRequest );
    }

}
```

build.gradle proyecto

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

build.gradle app

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.1.9'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.github.snowdream.android:smartimageview:0.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile files('libs/UnityAdsAdapter.jar')

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Admob configuracion

[image]

Unity Ads configuracion

[image]

Error LogCat

```
I/Ads: Starting ad request.
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0
```

Codigo Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:circular="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.badwolf.satoshimaker.Welcome"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_welcome">

<Button
android:text="Button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/ReclaimBit"
android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/history"
android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/history"
android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
android:id="@+id/button4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Hola @juan. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿Podrías especificar con mayor detalle qué problema estás teniendo? Si se está disparando un error, por favor incluye el stack trace. ¿Cuál es la pregunta en concreto? Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Comment: Hola pues no es un error de la aplicacion sino que no me carga el anuncio de video recompensado implementado en la aplicacion

Comment: Agrega tu layout por favor me parece que ese es el problema.

Comment: Acabo de añadirlo

Answer (score 0):

El error [onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/reward/RewardedVideoAdListener.html#onRewardedVideoAdFailedToLoad(int)) ocurre por un error al cargar el anuncio, en el LogCat se especifica el problema, agrega mas información.

Agrega el correcto `AdUnit`, si estas en desarrollo y no agregas el id correcto este se desplegaria en el LogCat.

El `AdUnit` especificado es incorrecto:

```
AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-000000000000000/00000000";
```

Comment: Hola este es el error que me sale en el LogCat al intentar cargarl el anuncio       I/Ads: Starting ad request.
W/Ads: There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads: Failed to load ad: 0

Comment: Pero es que no estoy poniendo ningun banner, estoy poniendo un video remunerado, estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: Este es el AdUnit que usas? AD_UNIT_ID = "ca-app-pub-000000000000000/00000000"; es in valor incorrecto.

Comment: He puesto ese por no poner el mio... Supuse que os imaginariais que hay pongo el mio correcto

Answer (score 0):

Ya ha pasado tiempo de que se hizo esta pregunta, pero puede que a mas de alguno le ayude.

Por lo que veo en el código buscas un video bonificado en vez de un anuncio intersticial y al parecer está todo correcto, creo que sólo falta inicializar los anuncios. Para ello agrega esto debajo del *setContentView()*:

> MobileAds.initialize(this, "YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID");

Con tu ADMOB_APP_ID debería quedar algo así:

> MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713");

**NOTA:** El *ADMOB_APP_ID* es distinto al *AD_UNIT_ID*.